# Pairwise non-integral numbers

Tags: definition

I have a set of complex numbers a_1 through a_n which are said to be "pairwise non-integral numbers".  Could someone explain to me exactly what this means?  Thanks.

**From comment below**:
I should also say the exact wording is "Pairwise different non-integral numbers".

Comment: Pairwise *coprime* is obvious but I don't know what it means for one complex quantity to be "integral" relative to another. What source is this said in?

Comment: You really ought to give some sense of context when looking for a definition.  Initially I'd guess it means that $a_i/a_j$ is not an integer when $i\neq j$.

Comment: It's in Freitag's Complex Analysis, p. 187.  It's in a chapter on applications of the residue theorem, and I'm looking at an analytic function f which is defined on C\{a_1,...,a_n}, where C stands for the complex plane.  Shoot, I should also say the exact wording is "Pairwise different non-integral numbers".  This is a not great english translation from german so it's possible something was lost in translation.

Comment: That just means they are pairwise different and all non-integers, if that is the wording.

Comment: Odd, Google Books has Freitag's "Complex Analysis 2" but not "Complex Analysis."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the alternate wording provided in comments, that seems just to mean a sequence of distinct complex numbers which are not integers.